# How to find the area and volume of Sphere and cylinder in same program in python

Tags: python

Task is to find the area and volume of the shapes. Consider the following shapes while designing the code: Sphere and Cylinder.
The class should have only one constructor. Also we should create a class called as Shape
Below is code i wrote and returning outputs, but how to use new class for shapes and inherit into test or the other way.

```
import math
#class Shapes
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.radius = args[0]
        if (len(args) == 2):
            self.height = args[1]
        self.area = 0
        self.volume = 0
        return super().__init__()

    def Area(self,val):
        radius = self.radius
        if (val == "Sphere"):
            area = 4 * 3.14  * radius ** 2
        elif (val =="Cylinder"):
            height = self.height
            area =   ((2 * 3.14  * radius) * (radius + height))
        else:
            area = 0
        return area


    def Volume(self,val):
        radius = self.radius
        if (val == "Sphere"):
            volume = (4/3) * (3.14  * radius ** 2)
        elif (val == "Cylinder"):
            height = self.height
            volume =   3.14  * radius * radius * height
        else:
            volume = 0
        return volume


def main():
    cylinder=Test(2,4) 
    print('Cylinder area:',cylinder.Area(enter code here'Cylinder'))
    print('Cylinder volume:',cylinder.Volume('Cylinder'))
    sphere=Test(3) 
    print('Sphere area:',sphere.Area('Sphere'))
    print('Sphere volume:',sphere.Volume('Sphere'))


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as specified in the question:

- Create a `class Shape`.
- Derive a `class Sphere` and a `class Cylinder` from this `class Shape`.
- Implement the calculation of volume and area for each shape.

Then, in order to use the shapes,

- You need to first create a shape.
- Then call the methods get_surface, or get_volume, on the shapes created. You do this with "dot" notation

The example here under does that.

```
import math

class Shape:
    """abstract class for shapes"""
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def get_surface(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_volume(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Sphere(Shape):    # <-- inherits from Shape
    def __init__(self, radius):
        Shape.__init__(self, radius)    # <-- can also use super().__init__(radius)

    def get_surface(self):
        return 4 * math.pi * self.radius**2   # <-- use math.pi constant i/o hard coding the value of pi

    def get_volume(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius**3 * 4/3  


class Cylinder(Shape):    # <-- inherits from Shape
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
        Shape.__init__(self, radius)    # <-- can also use super().__init__(radius)
        self.height = height

    def get_surface(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius * self.height + 2 * math.pi * self.radius**2

    def get_volume(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius**2 * self.height


def main():
    cyl = Cylinder(2, 4) 
    print('Cylinder area:', cyl.get_surface())   # <-- call the methods on the object
    print('Cylinder volume:', cyl.get_volume())
    sph = Sphere(5) 
    print('Sphere area:',sph.get_surface())
    print('Sphere volume:',sph.get_volume())


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

#### output:

```
Cylinder area: 75.3982236862
Cylinder volume: 50.2654824574
Sphere area: 314.159265359
Sphere volume: 523.598775598
```

Comment: This is the actual ask is.Create a class called Shape. Your task is to find the area and volume of the shapes. Consider the following shapes while designing the code: Sphere and Cylinder.The class should have only one constructor.import math
class Test:
def __init__(self, *args):
//writecode
return super().__init__()
def Area(self,val):
//write code
def Volume(self,val):
//writecode
def main():
sphere=Test(2)
print('Sphere area:',sphere.Area('Sphere'))
print('Sphere volume:',sphere.Volume('Sphere'))
cyclinder=Test(1,2) 
print('Cyclinder area:',cyclinder.Area('Cyclinder'))
main()

Comment: With Format
import math 
class Test: 
 def __init__(self, *args):
  //writecode
  return super().__init__()
 def Area(self,val): 
  //writecode
 def Volume(self,val): 
  //writecode
def main(): 
 sphere=Test(2) #inputs may change 
 print('Sphere area:',sphere.Area('Sphere')) 
 print('Sphere volume:',sphere.Volume('Sphere')) 
 cyclinder=Test(2,2) #inputs may change  
 print('Cyclinder volume:',cyclinder.Volume('Cyclinder')) 
if __name__=='__main__': main()